# importing dynamic web project in eclipse ?

Tags: eclipse, jsf, tomcat, myfaces

i use eclipse 3.6.2[Helios] and tomcat 7 and myfaces 1.2.10

i have a problem when i want to import a dynamic web project . i import the project in my workspace and perform the configurations and set jar files but when i run that in tomcat i will have this problem

```
HTTP Status 404 -

type Status report

message

description The requested resource () is not available.
Apache Tomcat/6.0.33
```

and in console display this error :

```
SEVERE: Error starting static Resources
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base C:\Eclipse\Workspaces\Wsp2\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\Wp1 does not exist or is not a readable directory
    at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.setDocBase(FileDirContext.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4320)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4489)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Oct 13, 2011 4:12:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error in resourceStart()
```

what should i do ?

thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse and Tomcat are both in confusion. I'd suggest to clean and rebuild all.

1. Remove project from Tomcat (rightclick Tomcat, *Add/Remove project*, remove project)
2. Close project in Eclipse (rightclick project, *Close*)
3. Clean Tomcat (rightclick Tomcat, *Clean*)
4. Reopen project in Eclipse (rightclick project, *Open*)
5. Clean project in Eclipse (*Project > Clean... > Clean selected projects below*, select project)
6. Add project to Tomcat (rightclick Tomcat, *Add/Remove projects*, add project)
7. Start Tomcat (rightclick Tomcat, *Start*).

Comment: thanx BalusC . i did all things that you said and the problem solved . thank you