# Eclipse java.lang.ClassNotFoundException -- class is most definitely on build path

Tags: eclipse, tomcat7, classnotfoundexception, buildpath

I cannot start my Eclipse JSF project on my Tomcat 7.0 server because I keep getting this ClassNotFound error, but I can clearly navigate to the class in the src folder, and I have confirmed that the containing package is on the project build path. What else should I be looking for to solve this issue? It was working perfectly fine yesterday, and now I turned off my computer and came back to it today only to find this..

Comment: Check if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941080/eclipse-webapp-project-does-not-start-properly-on-tomcat-anymore-after-a-pc-rest/10941265#10941265

Comment: Dose that class is actually deployed into Tomcat ? check tomcat folder in your workspace.

Comment: I figure there's a million reasons the work/build directories could get dirty?

Comment: also if you'd like a few points (I know you need them) you could post that as an answer, it worked